# Compile HttpServer from Dart to JS for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dart, dart2js

Is there some way to create http server on Dart that will be compiled to JS for Node JS?

If I try to use default server

```
HttpServer.bind(new InternetAddress("127.0.0.1"), 8081);
```

and then compile this code via dart2js I'll get error when node started

> Unsupported operation: InternetAddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `dart:io` when you want to build to JS because `dart:io` won't be available where the build output runs.
`dart:io` forwards to operating system calls and `dart2js` doesn't have any ability to translate such calls to JS (actually Node.js because JS itself doesn't provide any way at all)

You might need something like https://github.com/luizmineo/node-webkit.dart to use a custom implementation that translates to quivalent Node.js calls.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/misc/6GdnzJ2VqNI

Comment: However, dart2js succeeds when provided '--categories=Server' even when dart:io is used... Perhaps some of dart:io is ok to use, but not all.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. You can do that, but you need a JS implementation of `dart:io` which doesn't exist AFAIK but one could build a wrapper that forwards to an alternative implementation. Perhaps node-webkit.dart does something like that.